# Is there any way to access mipmaps in a GLSL 1.2 fragment program?

Tags: opengl, glsl, mipmaps

I would like to access different levels of detail in my GLSL fragment program. I'm currently stuck with using legacy OpenGL, including GLSL 1.2. Unfortunately, I don't have control over that.

I see that the `texture2DLod()` method exists, but it appears it can only be used in a vertex program.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635222/in-a-glsl-fragment-shader-how-to-access-to-texel-at-a-specific-mipmap-level), but they appear to be working with GLSL 1.4 or later. Unfortunately, I do not have that option.

Is there any way in a GLSL 1.2 fragment program to sample a specific mipmap level?

If there's no function for doing it directly, is it possible to send the mipmaps in as separate textures without doing 8 copies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for a fragment shader (in GLSL 1.20) to access a specific texture mipmap. However, you can always change [the base/max mipmap levels of a texture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Mipmap_range) before you use it. By setting them both to the same level, you force any texture accesses from that texture to use a specific mipmap level.

Now, you can't make these *separate* textures (unless you're using NVIDIA hardware and [have access to ARB_texture_view](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_views)). So you'll have to live with changing the texture's base/max level every time you want to pick a new mipmap.

Comment: OK, thanks for the info! I did make an implementation where I actually copy each mipmap level to a texture and access it that way, but I'm not sure performance will be good enough in that case. This is kind of an odd thing to want to do, I suppose, but thought I'd give it a try. Thanks!