# Reading levels of the hierarchical z buffer in a shader

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader

I know how to read values of the z buffer in a shader, by making giving a frame buffer a depth texture and then rendering to that and using the texture normally later.

However, for my purposes, I need to be able to read the bounding volumes that the higher levels of a hierarchical depth buffer would represent. My understanding is that modern depth buffers will use hierarchical z buffering, so is there any way I can utilize this with OpenGL?

If I can't, what are my options? Would I have to create the hierarchy by analyzing the depth texture on the CPU, and passing results to my shader?

Comment: There is no way to get this information. That is all very hardware specific, tied to the actual implementation of depth buffer compression and tiling. As for your second question, that is the last thing you would want to do - you should consider dispatching a compute shader job for something like this. In fact, there is even an article [here](http://www.nickdarnell.com/2010/06/hierarchical-z-buffer-occlusion-culling/) that discusses doing this using mipmaps to store the hierarchy; it is for HLSL, but you get the idea.

Comment: Is it not possible to have this going by enabling mipmapping an accessing a specific mip level in the shader. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635222/in-a-glsl-fragment-shader-how-to-access-to-texel-at-a-specific-mipmap-level) has some info on how to do this.